# Ansible throws an error with SSH connection reset when used under cygwin

Tags: ssh, ansible, cygwin

When I try to do anything, even something basic with ansible under cygwin, I get the following error:

```
$ ansible all -m ping
example.org | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: mm_send_fd: sendmsg(2): Connection reset by peer\r\nmux_client_request_session: send fds failed\r\n",
    "unreachable": true 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to `ansible.cfg` (either in the playbook folder or in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`):

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no
```

From what I've gathered, `ControlMaster=auto` also works, but under cygwin this option has to be disabled. [Source](https://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/automation/ansible-using-ansible-on-windows-via-cygwin/).